# how to get a Matlab timestamp in integer seconds

Tags: matlab, time

I need to get a timestamp in integer seconds, that won't roll over.
Can be elapsed CPU seconds, or elapsed clock or epoch seconds.

'clock' gives a date/time vector in years ... seconds.
But I can't figure out how to convert this to integer seconds.

cputime returns elapsed integer seconds but "This number can overflow the internal representation and wrap around.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `round(3600 * 24 * now)`?

According to the [manual](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/now.html), `now` returns the number of days since the year 0, as a floating point number. Multiplying by 86400 should thus give seconds.

Usually it is better to use a fixed-point format for keeping track of time, but since you are only interested in integer seconds, it should not be too much of a problem. The time resolution of `now` due to floating point resolution can be found like this:

```
>>  eps(now*86400)
ans =
   7.6294e-06
```

Or almost 8 microseconds. This should be good enough for your use case. Since these are 64-bit floating point numbers, you should not have to worry about wrapping around within your lifetime.

One practical issue is that the number of seconds since the year 0 is too large to be printed as an integer on the Matlab prompt with standard settings. If that bothers you, you can do `fprintf('%i\n', round(3600 * 24 * now))`, or simply subtract some arbitrary number, e.g. to get the number of seconds since the year 2000 you could do

```
epoch = datenum(2000, 1, 1);
round(86400 * (now - epoch))
```

which currently prints `488406681`.

Comment: It always returns 7.6294e-06 for me.  And round(3600*24*now) always returns 6.3602e+10.  Never changes.

Comment: @DougNull It does change, but you can't see it in E notation. You can go to Preferences -> Command Window -> Numeric format and change it to "long g" (as recommended by undocumented matlab)

Comment: @DougNull The time resolution will only change significantly if you wait 100 years. And that you do not see the integer seconds is just a printing issue, do `num2str(round(3600 * 24 * now))`, or `fprintf('%i\n', round(3600 * 24 * now))` to see the result ...

Comment: Awesome!  round(3600 * 24 * now) now works.  Thanks.